# Reopen a window and determine how it was closed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

There is a button on my main window which opens another window to gather some user input. If the user completes the input, the window should close. If the user clicks the red button, I need to show an alert and let the window close. In either case I need to be able to reopen the input window.

I can open the window the first time, but not close it programmatically nor can I reopen it. I have read all the posts I can find, and didn't find one I could apply to my case. I think my problem is an outlet, and delegate.

The delegate for the window is Calibrate.

Calibrate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
.
.
@interface Calibrate : NSWindowController
.
.
@end
```

Calibrate.m

```
#import "Calibrate.h"
Calibrate *calibrate;

- (IBAction)showCalibratePanel:(id)sender
{
  [calibrate showWindow:self];
}

- (void)handleMaxAngleChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  /////   last step in info gathering
  NSString *s = [[notification userInfo]objectForKey:@"myMaxAngleKey"];
  gotResponse = NO;
  [calibrate close];    //////////// does not close.
} 


#import "Calibrate.h"
@interface Calibrate () 
@end

@implementation Calibrate
.
.
- (id)init
{
  self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"Calibrate"];
  return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad 
{
  [super windowDidLoad];
}

-(BOOL)windowShouldClose:(NSNotification *)note
{  //// fires when red button clicked but alert not shown.
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Incomplete calibration may cause ERC to not work correctly."];
    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[NSApplication sharedApplication].mainWindow
                                        modalDelegate:nil 
                                        didEndSelector:nil     
                                        contextInfo:nil];

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: I think you should be looking at presenting this kind of thing in a sheet rather than a new window..

Comment: @Jef - I haven't used sheets before. What is the advantage?

Comment: A sheet is simply a dialog attached to a specific window, ensuring that a user never loses track of which window the dialog belongs to. The ability to keep a dialog attached to its pertinent window enables users to take full advantage of the OS X window layering model and also encourages modelessness; users can work on other documents or in other applications while a sheet is open.
(from apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Concepts/AboutSheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001043-BABFIBIA  )

Comment: I'll have to study that for a while. None of my texts or courses have mentioned sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[calibre.window close];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/close

To show the window use:

```
[calibrate showWindow:self];
```

as you did.

Comment: Sorry, but that did not work. Neither does orderOut.

Comment: I made Xcode project for you to try. Tell me if smthg. is wrong. http://tagtaxa.com//download/window.zip

Comment: Your example worked perfectly. I added your code to my program and made some progress. The red button closes the Calibrate window and shows the alert. I am still not able to close the Calibrate window from ORSSerialPortController(your MainWindowController) nor to reopen it. In my ORSSerialPortController @interface ORSSerialPortDemoController : NSObject <ORSSerialPortDelegate,             NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate> is different from yours.I cannot implement WindowDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I replaced the window with a panel, and all works as expected.